# Having trouble with a print button PDF in the record - Netsuite

Tags: javascript, pdf, netsuite, suitescript, clientscript

I am having some difficulty with a button I have added to a Inventory form. The button is added via a UE script at beforeLoad, which is tied to a function in a Client Script, which on click opens up a suitelet using an advanced pdf/html template which is populated by record data.

When I click on the button I get this error.

[Img Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO9UL.png)

This is my code

**CLIENTSCRIPT**

> ```
> /**
>  * @NApiVersion 2.x
>  * @nScriptType ClientScript 
>  * @ModuleScope SameAccount
>  */
>     
>
>     define(['N/url', 'N/currentRecord'], function(url, currentRecord) {
>         var exports = {};
>
>     function pageInit(context){
>     }
>
>     exports.pageInit = pageInit;
>
>     function onButtonClick(context){
>         try{
>             /*var record = currentRecord.get();
>             var recId = record.id;
>             var recType = record.type;*/
>             var suiteletUrl = url.resolveScript({
>                 scriptId : 'customscript_createbutton_st', //Script ID de mi entorno Suitelet
>                 deploymentId: 'customdeploy_createbutton_st',  //Deployment ID de mi entorno Suitelet
>                 returnExternalUrl: false,
>                 params: {
>                     recordId: currentRecord.get().id
>                 }
>             });
>             window.open(suiteletUrl);
>         }catch(e){
>             console.log(e.message);
>         }
>     }
>
>     exports.onButtonClick = onButtonClick;
>     exports.pageInit = pageInit;
>     return exports;
> });
> ```

**SUITELET**

> ```
> /**
>  * @NApiVersion 2.x
>  * @NScriptType Suitelet 
>  * @appliedtorecord transaction
>  */
>
>  define(['N/render', 'N/record', 'N/xml', 'N/format', 'N/error'], function(render, record, xml, format, error) {
>     function onRequest(context){
>             var recordId = context.request.parameters.recordId;
>           var pdfFileName = "Recuento de Invetario";
>           var renderer = render.create();
>           var content =  renderer.addRecord({
>               templateName: 'Inventario',
>               record: record.load({
>                   type: record.Type.INVENTORY_COUNT,
>                   id: recordId
>               })
>           });
>         
>           renderer.setTemplateByScriptId('custtmpl _vm_recuento_inventario');
>           context.response.setHeader({
>               name: 'content-disposition',
>               value: 'inline; filename"' + pdfFileName + '_' + recordId + '.pdf"'
>           });
>        context.response.writeFile(renderer.renderAsPdf());
>
>   }   
>   return{
>       onRequest: onRequest
>   }
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

On your User Event Script, you should pass your ID only and NOT the whole context. Its either setting the `recordId` as undefined/null so the Suitelet throws the `SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT` error due to an invalid ID.