# NetSuite - Suite Script Error - Print PDF Button - Type : job

Tags: javascript, pdf, netsuite, suitescript

I have created a print pfd button on my project record. The intention is build a pdf project summary to send to clients. When I click the button I get a Suite Script Error.

This is my error.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm1Ij.png)

**EVENTSCRIPT**

```
define([],function () {
    var exports = {};
    function beforeLoad(context) {
        context.form.addButton({
            id: "custpage_mybutton",
            label: "Print Project Summary",
            functionName: "onButtonClick"
        });
        context.form.clientScriptModulePath = "SuiteScripts/job_cs_test_message.js"
    }

    exports.beforeLoad = beforeLoad;
    return exports;
});
```

**CLIENTSCRIPT**

```
define(["N/url", "N/currentRecord"], function(url, currentRecord) {
    var exports = {};

    function pageInit(context) {
        // TODO
    }

    function onButtonClick() {
        var suiteletUrl = url.resolveScript({
          scriptId: 'customscript_job_su_printpdf',
          deploymentId: 'customdeploy_job_su_printpdf',
          returnExternalUrl: false,
          params: {
            custom_id: currentRecord.get().id,
          },
        });
        window.open(suiteletUrl);
      }

    exports.onButtonClick = onButtonClick;
    exports.pageInit = pageInit;
    return exports;
});
```

**SUITELET**

```
define(['N/render', 'N/file', 'N/record'],
    function(render, file, record) 
    {
        function onRequest(context) {
        function renderRecordToPdfWithTemplate() {
            var custom_id = context.request.parameters.custom_id;
            var xmlTemplateFile = file.load('Templates/PDF Templates/custtmpl_job_pdf_test.xml');
            var renderer = render.create();
            renderer.templateContent = xmlTemplateFile.getContents();
            renderer.addRecord('record', record.load({
                type: record.Type.JOB,
                id: custom_id
            }));
            var invoicePdf = renderer.renderAsPdf();
        }
        renderRecordToPdfWithTemplate();
    }
        return {
            onRequest: onRequest
          }
    });
```

**XML**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
 
 <pdf>
 <head>
 <meta name="title" value="My First Document"/>
 </head>
 <body background-color="yellow" font-size="18">
 Hello, World!
 </body>
 </pdf>
```

I have tried many variations, focusing mainly on the addRecord command. I did this because it initially worked in the employee record, so I was working on the assumption it was the move to a project record that caused this issue.

That being said, I recently found a [related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74791629/having-trouble-with-a-print-button-pdf-in-the-record-netsuite) which I think holds the real answer. However, it was not updated by the person who asked the questions.

It suggests only passing the ID and not the whole context. I'll be honest, I didn't really know what that meant.

Comment: The error indicates the issue is in your XML template file.  You should post that too.

Comment: I have edited the post with XML. It was just basic to prove I could get it working before developing the pdf in full.